# Count the number of rows returned in SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a little problem, my query look like this

```
select count(A.toto)
from B
inner join C
on B.tata = C.tata
inner join A
on C.tutu = A.tutu
group by A.toto, A.zaza, A.zozo;
```

and my result look like this :

```
1
2
1
6
7
4
1
1
1
```

But I want only the number of rows, for this example, the value that I would like to have is **9**.
But I don't know how I can have this value...
Thank you in advance !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `count(distinct)`.  Unfortunately, Oracle doesn't support `count(distinct)` with multiple arguments, so a typical method is just to concatenate the value together:

```
select count(distinct A.toto || ':' || A.zaza || ':' || A.zozo)
from B inner join
     C
     on B.tata = C.tata inner join
     A
     on C.tutu = A.tutu;
```

This assumes that. the column values don't have the separator character (or at least in such a way that the concatenation is the same for rows with different key values).

An alternative method is to use a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select 1
      from B inner join
           C
           on B.tata = C.tata inner join
           A
           on C.tutu = A.tutu
      group by A.toto, A.zaza, A.zozo
     ) abc
```

Comment: I think the first query works wth nulls as well since Oracle convert nulls to '' (empty string) while concatenating.